# How to pass multiple values in where statement in SSIS variable?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I'm creating a SSIS package which has two variables that is going to assign values into another SQL Command variable. The data source is an ODBC connector and the destination is an OLEDB connector.

Variables name:

- vPurchaseType (multiple values)
- vTransactionDate (single value)
- vPSourceQuery (SQL statement that is receive the others two variables)

One variable is a single row, this one it's working. The other variable is multiple values that is going to be ingested in a `IN` clause. But I'm not being able to pass multiple values in this one, I already tried `Single row` or `Full result set` but also doesn't work.

First variable result (vPurchaseType):

**Query example:**

```
SELECT Head FROM TableB
```

| Head |
| --- |
| 12 |
| 9C |
| AA |

*The second variable must be between single quotes in order to work.*

Second variable result (vTransactionDate):

**Query example:**

```
SELECT Head FROM TableA
```

| Head |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01 |

Third variable:

```
SELECT
  ColA,
  ColB,
  ColC,
  ColD
FROM TableC
WHERE ColC >= '"+ @[User::vTransactionDate] + "'
AND ColD IN ("+ @[User::vPurchaseType] +")
```

My package:

[image]

Comment: You can't  - at least not the way you're doing things. What is the source RDBMS that populates vPurchaseType?

Comment: That's bad. Can you please show me the way? I'm quite new at SSIS. The source is Teradata.

Comment: Why are you injecting and not using parameters?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean @Larnu? The only parameters that I'm using is about permissions (user and password), the SQL scripts is variables.

Comment: `ColC >= '"+ @[User::vTransactionDate] + "'` that is injection. You are *injecting* the variable into the string. A *major* security vulnerability. Always, always, always parametrise.

Comment: I see, unfortunately that's a requirement because the data comes from the db and not from the parameter sadly. That's why I came to ask help, but thank you for the heads up anyway @Larnu!

Comment: No, no it's not a "requirement". Having a massive security vulnerability is *never* a requirement unless the goal is to explain to others how bad a security issue it is. Execute T-SQL Tasks support parametrisation; use it. It's not the 1990's any more. There is a reason companies that make such stupid mistakes are named, shamed, and fined millions of {currency}; to finger point and make an example so that others know that it's not acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I'm using the solution of this article from [MyTecBits - SQL Server: Concatenate Multiple Rows Into Single String](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/concatenate-multiple-rows-into-single-string#:%7E:text=You%20can%20concatenate%20rows%20into,the%20COALESCE%20to%20the%20variable.), and applying that to my variable **vPurchaseType**, and receiving the values as `Single Row`. But I had to change the query a little bit, by using the function `CAST AS VARCHAR (4000)` to accept all the data from my column.

After that I changed my `Data Flow`, and did the swap from `OLEDB Destination` to `ADO Net Destination`, I also had to mark the option `ValidadeExternalMetadata` as `False`, and that's it! Now is working.